# can't pickle weakref objects

Tags: serialization, pyspark, pickle, folium

I'm trying to use spark to extract spatial data from a csv and represent it in a folium map.

While using the foreach() function i get a **PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle weakref objects**

i understand as described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) that not all types can be pickled, however i need this folium map type to be pickled ,in order to visualize my data.

the github owners of folium answered me [here](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/878) that **folium object can't be pickled**.

what should i do ?

How to make the folium objects serializable ?
Is there an alternative for pickle that can serialize folium objects ?